# Digital makeup for Mystique

Tags: film-techniques, x-men-cinematic-universe, costume

I was reading recently that the grueling makeup process for Mystique was the main reason why Jennifer Lawrence isn't interested in making more x-men films.

It seems like the obvious solution would be to put her in a motion capture suit. Then after filming, bodypaint her (or a body double), scan the costume in, and digitally add the costume onto her.

Are there good reasons why they can't do this?

Answer (score 4):

They did.

They managed to reduce the makeup time, [from eight hours to three](http://www.businessinsider.com/jennifer-lawrence-x-men-mystique-makeup-2014-5). They did this by only doing makeup on her face/head, but I guess three hours is still too much (would be for me, at least)

Comment: That begs the question. why did they only go halfway? from what I read they still did the full bodypaint for close up shots.

Comment: paying for 8 hours of makeup for closeups is a lot cheaper than rendering the same thing for a similar quality.

Comment: I'm thinking at some point in the future all actors will wear mocap suits and have their costumes added digitally. When you look at the batman films most of the actors found the suits restricted them and in the latest version it cost $100,000 to make. At the moment it probably costs more to render an outfit. But costume changes take time and people and that all adds up. Maybe an uncomfortable 8 hours of makeup isn't worth it when Jennnifer could be using that time doing voice over work instead.

Comment: that happens now, for high budget films. iron man was nearly completely cgi - http://i.stack.imgur.com/PndD8.gif

Answer (score 0):

To give it a more realistic view?

CGI costumes don't always look good on screen. You can take an example from [Green Lantern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Lantern_(film)), where a full CGI costume was made into a blunder and got criticized a lot. It was even made into a joke by the actor himself in the Deadpool trailer.

Now it can also be argued with the example of Iron-Man where it did worked quite well.

The same thing applies to body paints too. For Two Face they opted for a [mixture of CGI and makeup](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/9177/1190). Now it's up to the director to decide what they want, but overall it can be said that real costume/body paint will look more realistic then CGI.